# How to Use Rhino Mock in unit testing

Tags: unit-testing

i am new to unittesting with rhino mocks and i am confused how to mock my dependency which are initialized in controller constructor using unity container.

as per the below code i have to unittest "GetHelloWorld" method with two dependency TestRepository and  RedisCacheManager   .

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    private ITestRepository testRepo;
    private IRedisCacheManager cacheManager;

    public TestController()
    {
        testRepo = UnityResolver.Resolve<ITestRepository>();
        cacheManager = UnityResolver.Resolve<IRedisCacheManager>();
    }

    public ActionResult GetHelloWorld()
    {
        LoggerHelper.WriteInfo("Inside GetHelloWorld Method..");
        testRepo.PutDataInCustomAzureDB();
        cacheManager.Add("Test", "TestData", new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
        var getData = cacheManager.Get<string>("Test");
        cacheManager.Add("Test", "TestData123", new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
        var getDataa = cacheManager.Get<string>("Test");
        LoggerHelper.WriteInfo("Leaving GetHelloWorld Method..");
        return null;
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have a separate `UnityResolver` for the unit test project and there you have to send mock objects in the `Resolve` method. That is have a separate `container` for the unit test project and then

```
Mock<IRedisCacheManager> _mockRedis = new Mock<IRedisCacheManager>();
container.RegisterInstance <IRedisCacheManager>(_mockRedis.Object);
```

Another way of doing this would be to inject the `resolver` or the dependencies in the class itself